# Is there any way to make a generic method with Nullable<T> as parameter?

Tags: c#, .net

I have this method:

```
public T ToEnumTypeOf<T>(this int enumValue, T dest) where T : Enum 
    => (T)(object)enumValue
```

I want to change it to take Nullable as parameter. like:

```
public T ToEnumTypeOf<T>(this int enumValue, Nullable<T> dest) where T : Enum 
    => (T)(object)enumValue
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: what's the purpose if the `test`-paramater at all? Just to have a static type? It's not used anywhwre despite the generic argument.

Comment: btw.: you know `Enum.TryParse`? Seems like you want to re-implement that.

Comment: and why not simply return `T?`, if you really want a nullable?

Comment: input of "Enum.TryParse" is string. but my input is int

Comment: You can have nullable parameters with the proper type constraint but this method is already implemented

Comment: `my input is int` in that case you don't need any method. Enums are aliases for ints. You can pass ints to any method expecting an enum (or rather any number of the same base type as the enum). That's actually one of the problems with enums - the compiler doesn't check the values. You can cast any number to an enum.

Comment: This code makes little sense to me, since the `dest`-parameter is not used. Either remove that parameter, or make it a `out`-parameter. I would also question the idea to make this an extension method of `int`. Conversion from primitives to actual types and back again should typically be done in an outer layer, so the vast majority of code can use the correct types for the data.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos true but there's always somebody that decides they want to `ushort` or some other integral type other than the default!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`where T : Enum` basically doesn't work as you expect; it isn't "any concrete enum", since `Enum` itself must work. The closest you can get is `where T : struct`, and check `typeof(T).IsEnum`

Comment: Actually you can just add `struct` to constraints, not replace it: `where T : struct, Enum` and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Add `struct` generic constraint:

```cs
T ToEnumTypeOf<T>(int enumValue, T? dest) where T : struct, Enum
    => (T)(object)enumValue;
```

Compiler does not assume `struct` constraint for [`System.Enum` one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters#enum-constraints) automatically. See examples from [breakdown of new generic constraints in C# 7.3](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-new-generics-constraints-in-c-7-3/#the-enum-constraint).

Note that this will fail in runtime if `Enum`'s underlying type is not `int`:

```cs
enum MyEnum : byte
{
    One = 1
}

MyEnum dest = default;
ToEnumTypeOf<MyEnum>(1, dest); // Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'MyEnum'
```

Quick and dirty approach to fix this conversion via string (though not very performant one):

```cs
T ToEnumTypeOf<T>(int enumValue, T? dest) where T : struct, Enum
    => Enum.Parse<T>(enumValue.ToString());
```

Note that this will not throw for invalid enum values (as your current code, i.e. `ToEnumTypeOf<MyEnum>(2, dest)` will work just fine for example above).